# -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 ineffective for devtoolset-7 on CentOS 7

Tags: c++, gcc, redhat-dts

Recently, I noticed that my program has a big performance regression because [the standard library implementation of gcc with version earlier than 5 makes `list::size()` an `O(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751799/560648).

I'm using CentOS 7.2 whose default gcc version is 4.8.5. So I installed scl and devtoolset-7, and rebuilt my program. However, I found that `list::size()` in my program is still an `O(n)` method, even if I explicitly make `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to 1.

Why? It's odd.

Answer (score 10):

It is forcefully disabled in RHEL6/7.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704